# Numbers to words converter C++ coding

Tags: c++

I'd to write a c++ project for my school that read and converts numbers in D:\Data\Input.txt to words and write them at bottom of Input.txt
I'd wrote the following code but it doesn't run good, its output for numbers below 15 isn't correct for example it converts 5 to two or 6 to twelve, etc.
I don't know how to solve its problems.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream> 

using namespace std;

int q=0;
char ch[100][100];
char out[5000];

void first_digit(int yeki)
{
    if (yeki<20)
        switch (yeki)
        {
        case 1:
            strcpy(ch[q],"one");
            break;
        case 2:
            strcpy(ch[q],"two");
            break;
        case 3: 
            strcpy(ch[q],"three");
            break;
        case 4:
            strcpy(ch[q],"four");
            break; 
        case 5:
            strcpy(ch[q],"five");
            break;
        case 6:
            strcpy(ch[q],"six");
            break;
        case 7:
            strcpy(ch[q],"seven");
            break;
        case 8:
            strcpy(ch[q],"eight");
            break;
        case 9:
           strcpy(ch[q],"nine");
            break;
        case 10:
            strcpy(ch[q],"ten");
            break;
        case 11:
            strcpy(ch[q],"eleven");
            break;
        case 12:
            strcpy(ch[q],"twelve");
            break;
        case 13:
            strcpy(ch[q],"thirteen");
            break;
        case 14:
            strcpy(ch[q],"fourteen");
            break;
        case 15:
            strcpy(ch[q],"fifteen");
            break;
        case 16:
            strcpy(ch[q],"sixteen");
            break;
        case 17:
            strcpy(ch[q],"seventeen");
            break;
        case 18:
            strcpy(ch[q],"eighteen");
            break;
        case 19:
            strcpy(ch[q],"nineteen");
            break;   
        }
        q++;
    }

void second_digit(int dahi)
{
    int a,b;

    a=(dahi/10)%10;
    b=dahi%10;
    first_digit(b);
    if (b!=0)
    {
        strcpy(ch[q]," - ");
        q++; 
    }
    switch (a)
    {
    case 2:
        strcpy(ch[q],"twenty");
        break;
    case 3: 
        strcpy(ch[q],"thirty");
        break;
    case 4:
        strcpy(ch[q],"forty");
        break; 
    case 5:
        strcpy(ch[q],"fifty");
        break;
    case 6:
        strcpy(ch[q],"sixty");
        break;
    case 7:
        strcpy(ch[q],"seventy");
        break;
    case 8:
        strcpy(ch[q],"eighty");
        break;
    case 9:
        strcpy(ch[q],"ninety");
        break;
    } 
    q++; 
}

void third_digit(int sadi)
{
    int a,b;
    a=sadi/100;
    b=sadi-(a*100);
    if(b<20) 
        first_digit(b);
    if(b>19) 
        second_digit(b);
    if(b!=0)
    {
        strcpy(ch[q]," and ");
        q++;
    }
    switch(a){
    case 1:
        strcpy(ch[q],"one hundred");
        break;
    case 2:
        strcpy(ch[q],"two hundred");
        break;
    case 3:
        strcpy(ch[q],"three hundred");
        break;
    case 4:
        strcpy(ch[q],"four hundred");
        break;
    case 5:
        strcpy(ch[q],"five hundred");
        break;
    case 6:
        strcpy(ch[q],"six hundred");
        break;
    case 7:
        strcpy(ch[q],"seven hundred");
        break;
    case 8:
        strcpy(ch[q],"eight hundred");
        break;
    case 9:
        strcpy(ch[q],"nine hundred");
        break;
    }
    q++;
}

string numberProcess(string number)
{
    char s[20],s1[number.length()+1];
    strcpy(s1, number.c_str()); 
    int i,j,k=8,n,p=0,l=1,sefr=0, x[9];
    int va2,va;
    j=number.length()+1;

    strcpy(s,s1); 
    for (i=1 ;i<=8;i++)
        x[i]=0;
    for (i=j-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        n=s[i]-48;
        if (l==1000) 
        {
            l=1;
            k--;
        }
        x[k]=x[k]+(n*l);
        l=l*10;
    }
    for (i=1;i<=8;i++) 
        sefr=sefr+x[i];
    if(sefr==0)
    {
        strcpy(ch[q],"zero");
        q++; 
    }
    else
    {
        for (i=8;i>=1;i--)
        if (x[i]!=0)
        {
            va2=0;
            for (va=8;va>=i+1;va--)
                va2=va2+x[va];
            if(va2 != 0)
            {
                strcpy(ch[q]," and ");
                q++;
            }

            switch(i)
            {
            case 7:
                strcpy(ch[q]," Thousand ");
                break;
            case 6:
                strcpy(ch[q]," Million ");
                break;
            case 5:
                strcpy(ch[q]," billion ");
                break;
            case 4:
                strcpy(ch[q]," Trillions ");
                break;
            case 3:
                strcpy(ch[q]," Quadrillion ");
                break;
            case 2:
                strcpy(ch[q]," Quintilion ");
                break;  
            }
            q++;
            if (x[i]<20)  
                first_digit(x[i]);
            if ((x[i]>19)&&(x[i]<100))  
                second_digit(x[i]);
            if (x[i]>99)  
                third_digit(x[i]);
        }
        return out;
    }  


    for(int df = 100; df>=0;df--)
    {
        if(strcmp(ch[df],""  ))  
        strcat(out ,ch[df]); 
    }

}

int main(){
    ifstream datas;
    string line;
    datas.open("da.txt",ios::out);
    if(datas)
    {
        while(getline(datas,line))
        {
            cout<<numberProcess(line);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: did you try running it with debugger?

Comment: A programming language is mostly designed not to translate your ideas to the computer but... to translate your ideas to another developer. Keep that in mind when you code and especially when you public something. Inconsistent identations, braces, cryptographic naming, etc... -- all this makes it impossible for others to understand your work in a reasonable amount of time. What is worse - even you cannot understand your code. My recommendation: fix the formatting and try to debug.

Comment: It's pretty clear just from how complicated that code is that there are poroblems with it. What the initial part of `numberProcess` is doing is a mystery.

Comment: `char s1[number.length()+1];` is a variable-length array and not part of standard C++. You could remove the C++ code and use C or you could use a STL container (std::string or std::vector) for this.

Comment: also all your arrays start at 1 not in 0

Comment: As sated in other comments, you should consider refactoring your code to make it more readable. Other than that, it could be helpful if you provide an example of problematic input file so we can also evaluate the exact case you have problems with.